# Jquery load and ajax on webmatrix

Tags: jquery, webmatrix

This is a huge challenge to my webmatrix layout. I have a site layout `_sitelayout.cshtml`, a  renderbody page `profilepage.cshtml` and an independent page `ajaxload.cshtml`. The sitelayout's script library is updated using the `Assets.GetScripts()` from profilepage.cshtml. Each time i call the ajaxload.cshtml using `$.load()`...After successful load i cant interact with any javascript/plugin file on the mother page and profilepage.cshtml. I must  call the javascript plugins using `$.getScript()` or attach it manually using `<script src=""></script>`which calls the javascript file again before use.

**Profilepage.cshtml**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Layout/_sitelayout.cshtml";
Assets.Script("~/scripts/autocomplete.js");
....
....
}
```

Its quite difficult to explain this....hope u understand

Comment: use firebug to see whether your page is loading the scripts from correct path

Comment: @Shyju.....I've done that. Every script is in place and loaded also.